# Why doesn't excel Solver respect the variable bounds?

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I explicitly set bounds for the values the variables could take on.  Yet the optimizer regularly ignores these and tests values outside of those bounds.  Why and how to stop this from happening?  It would solve so many problems if it'll just respect the boundaries I have specified.

And you know what, if you use Evolution, it forces you to set boundaries for variables, yet it still doesn't respect them.  Like what's the point?

Comment: Yup I've had the same. I think it tries everything but will consider the solution good only if its within bounds. Like its not the operating space, but the preferred space? I hate solver for the most part.

Comment: Hi @confused could you plz [edit] your post and share some sample data with us,,help us to fix it !